# Rounding down in Power BI with a specific start time

Tags: powerbi, rounding

I have a dataset around timesheeting for staff and the number of clients consulted at particular times. We are wanting to look at how many clients are consulted in 15min intervals. I have done the following:

"Consult slot", each Time.From(Number.RoundDown(96*Number.From(Time.From([Shift]))/1)/96))

This works well if most people start their shifts at normal 15min intervals within the hour (i.e. 0800, 0815, 0830 etc), but what about where the shift may start at 0805. In this instance I want the 15minute intervals to display as 0805, 0820, 0835 etc

My dataset has two tables relevant to this query.

One has the timesheet data such as:

| Staff ID | Timesheet date | Timesheet start time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 01/02/2023 | 08:05:00am |
| B246 | 01/02/2023 | 09:00:00am |

...and the other has our client visits:

| Staff ID | Date of visit | Time consulted | Consult slot |  | Should be |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 01/02/2023 | 08:26:00am | 08:15:00am | (incorrect) | 08:20:00am |
| A123 | 01/02/2023 | 08:39:00am | 08:30:00am | (incorrect) | 08:35:00am |
| B246 | 01/02/2023 | 09:10:00am | 09:00:00am | (correct) | 09:00:00am |

Currently the formula (above) is populating the column "Consult slot", but for staff member A123, their slots should be displaying 15min increments FROM their start time of 08:05:00am.

Is there a way to do this please?!

Thank you
Megan

I tried the following query:
"Consult slot", each Time.From(Number.RoundDown(96*Number.From(Time.From([Shift]))/1)/96))

But have recently discovered the start time of the shift differs and isn't always on your standard 15min increment (8am, 8.15am, 8.30am, 8.45am for example).